# Real world sizing of objects with a target Linear Measurement

Tags: scale, measurement

I have scanned sculptures that need to be scaled up or down. Then what I am given is a measurement between two topographical features (like pupils). So I need to scale the object up till that linear measurement matches the need.
Now I can do this quite clunkily by making a target object of that measurement and hand scaling the sculpture till it mostly fits. But it's not exact and rather a poor way to go at it.

What I am looking for is a CAD feature that Allows me to make the same measurement on the object then change that measurement by typing in a new one and in turn scaling the entire object appropriately.

Strangely enough Lychee Slicer can do this well. ie a Measurement tool that snaps to the object and will not only give you the current measurement but if that measurement is manually changed will scale the tool AND object its snapped to appropriately.

My question is Does Blender have a better way to do this? A similar way described above to do this task built in or a Addon that allows you to do this??
I keep searching and because scaling in blender historically was a bit confusing (applying it etc) all I get in searches is that.

Any help here would be great as I am trying to streamline a process that will need to be done over and over.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use the Measure tool to measure the current distance, and then enter a simple division equation in the scale fields, one at a time (or using copy-paste from the first one). Will this work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I need to use the provided linear measurement not a overall scale of enlargement, that measurement is the driving factor. Or I am not understanding what equation you are suggesting in the scale fields, please elaborate.  
I am thinking you are proposing a proportional equation? of the linear measurements and then apply proportion to the scale?  
If so I was really hoping for something Much simpler as I said I was trying to streamline this for artists to do quickly.   But that would work if that is what you are proposing.

Comment: Well, to state it formulaically, for any two points in a mesh A and B, given the desired distance between them D and the current distance between them E (both distances measured in 3D space), the appropriate scale for the whole object, so that D=E, is E/D on all three axes.

Comment: Yes, and I was able to find a Addon with a UI that helps with that.  Again I am trying to simplify and streamline for others that really don't do math. (really don't)
The Lychee Slicer has a great tool for this and I was looking for something similar that people could relate to. 
I never thought of just using "proportional" as a key word and that worked to filter out all the blender Applying scaling advice.
So you where a great help, Thanks.